# Different border spacing for different rows

Tags: html, css, html-table, semantic-markup

**Synopsis:** I need to display a table like the one below:

[image: table with different spacing between head and body]

**Necessities:**

- Semantic HTML coding
- No scripting

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan=2>
            One
        </th>
        <th colspan=2>
            Two
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            One
        </td>
        <td>
            Two
        </td>
        <td>
            Three
        </td>
        <td>
            Four
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            One
        </td>
        <td>
            Two
        </td>
        <td>
            Three
        </td>
        <td>
            Four
        </td>
    </tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

---

**First attempt:**

*"border-collapse attribute"*

I tried `border-collapse: separate;` on `thead` and `border-collapse: collapse;` on `tbody` but that simply didn't work.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 1em;
}

table thead {
    border-collapse: separate;
}

table tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

table thead tr th{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

table tbody tr td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}​
```

[On JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tw5Vb/2/)

---

**Second Attempt:**

*"Adding blank cells"*

I can get the preferred look of the table by adding blank cells in HTML code. But this approach defects semantic structure.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 1em;
}

table tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

table thead tr th[colspan="2"]{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

table tbody tr td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}​
```

[On JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tw5Vb/1/)

---

**Other various attemps**

I also tried `-webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, black 95%, white 5%);` on headers borders but couldn't manage to get it working.

---

After all I am open to new suggestions.

**Note:**
This is going to be in an eBook file. So general background color may vary in different reader applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your compatibility requirements, you have the option of using CSS generated-content:

```
th {
    /* other CSS */
    position: relative;
}

thead th::before,
thead th::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    width: 0.5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

thead th::before {
    left: 0;
}

thead th::after {
    right: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Tw5Vb/7/).

For the sake of simplicity I've given *both* `th` elements the same `::before` and `::after`, however if there's always only two `th` elements the selectors can be changed:

```
th {
    /* other CSS */
    position: relative;
}

thead th:first-child::after,
thead th:last-child::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    width: 0.5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

thead th:last-child::before {
    left: 0;
}

thead th:first-child::after {
    right: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Tw5Vb/10/).

Comment: Why add absolute-positioned generated content when you can pad the `th` element instead?

Comment: you need to watch out for positioned elements directly inside table cells because firefox doesn't position things relative to cells properly

Comment: @Rémi: because, as far as I'm aware, the `padding` doesn't affect the `border-bottom`'s length. Which seems to be the requirement.

Answer (score 7):

[Here's my try](http://jsfiddle.net/6YSTH/).

Basically I just did:

```
table thead tr th[colspan="2"]:first-child {
    border-right: 20px solid white;
}
table thead tr th[colspan="2"]:nth-child(2) {
    border-left: 20px solid white;
}
```

**Note:** I personally wouldn't use such complex selectors, but this should give you the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It sure is a good approach but i forgot to mention that it is supposed to be in an eBook (ePub3). So background color may vary on the reader applications preferences and setting border-color to transparent kills the magic.

Comment: In general, I recommend to carefully test this “kind of magic” on older versions of Internet Explorer that you might be expected to support.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding white borders. You then need to turn them off from the first and last cells.

```
table thead tr th{
    border-left: solid 10px white;
    border-right: solid 10px white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
table thead tr th:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
table thead tr th:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Here's an updated js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/davetayls/Tw5Vb/9/

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers.

Comment: this wasn't duplicate when i posted it

Comment: @DaveTaylor Check out the timestamps.

Comment: @Abody97 i know, i was composing mine while you submitted yours! looking closer, this is actually slightly different from your even though it is the same concept. it uses less complicated selectors. don't be so quick to mark down.

Comment: @DavidThomas take a look at the jsfiddle, it does exactly what was asked

Comment: @Dave: agreed, I just didn't read the posted CSS properly. (Original comment deleted).

Comment: Although it has the same concept, it is different to @Abody97's answer. It was my fault not to mention about background-colors. I think this answer doesn't deserve negative points. +1